# How To Declare Flow<PagingData<Data>> as Variable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, paging, android-paging-3, data-paging

I am trying to fetch API data with peging 3 library. I am following [this tutorial](https://proandroiddev.com/pagination-in-jetpack-compose-with-and-without-paging-3-e45473a352f4). However, the API is called multiple times. I assume it's because of this code in compose:

```
 val documentList = dashboardViewModel.getBreakingNews().collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```

Here is the code of view model

```
fun getBreakingNews(

    ): Flow<PagingData<Data>> = getNews().cachedIn(viewModelScope)



    fun getNews() = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            DocPagingSource(arkeliyaApiService)
        }
    ).flow
```

I want to declare `Flow<PagingData<Data>>` like I did with other APIs

For example

```
 private val _listofReqDoc = MutableStateFlow<List<Data>>(listOf())
    val listofReqDoc = _listofReqDoc.asStateFlow()
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
val breakingNews = Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(
        pageSize = 10,
    ),
    pagingSourceFactory = {
        DocPagingSource(arkeliyaApiService)
    }
).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

val documentList = dashboardViewModel.breakingNews.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```